# Periodic or non periodic function plotting

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions, delay-differential-equations

I am currently working on plotting a function and figuring out if its periodic or not. The function is as follows:$$x_n=\beta\cdot x_{n-1}+\alpha\gamma\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(x_{n-3})+\alpha(1-\gamma)\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(x_{n-2})$$
I know $0<\beta<1$, $\alpha<0$, $0<\gamma<1$. Note that $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

I have created an app on MATLAB which helps me figure out if it is periodic or not depending on the three initial values I start with. I have noticed that it can be $1$, $3$ or $4$-periodic so far.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to write this mathematically.
I am trying to find a negative delay. Any hints or sources that I can use would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your question throws up a lot of questions in my mind, but I think I can answer your last question: you can't. This is a recursive definition of a sequence, so you'll need to choose some initial values (two of them). If you nominate some values for $x_1$ and $x_2$, then you can compute $x_3$ from them, then $x_4$, $x_5$, etc. Without specifying initial values, there will typically be infinitely many sequences that satisfy a given recurrence relation.

Comment: @TheoBendit what about $x_{n-3}$? Does it not need three initial values? How do i nominate $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ to compute $x_{3}$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed $x_{n-3}$. You do indeed need to nominate *three* initial values.

Comment: @TheoBendit so would you say that is the correct way to find $x_4$ as I did above?

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.

Comment: @TheoBendit I really appreciate your help. Sorry for bothering you so many times.

Comment: It's no bother. :-)

Comment: @Saad sorry about that. I am working on the following function and I am trying to plot it and figuring out if it is periodic or non-periodic. I have started with the three initial values and then found x4 x5 and so on. Now I was wondering if those values do not graph a periodic function does that mean that the function is not period or are there other values that I can start with in order to achieve a period function. Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @Hidaw So basically you want to find all the initial values that make this function periodic?

Comment: @Saad if its possible yes

Comment: @Saad so I have been instructed. Please if you do think it should be 0<γ<1 I am would be more than happy to try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$In this answer it is always assumed that $0 < β, γ < 1$ and $α \in \mathbb{R}^*$.

---

Define $ε_n = \sgn(x_n)$ for $n \geqslant 1$, then the recurrence relation becomes$$
x_n = βx_{n - 1} + α(1 - γ) ε_{n - 2} + αγ ε_{n - 3}
$$
and it can be proved by induction that$$
x_n = β^{n - 3} x_3 + α(1 - γ) \sum_{k = 2}^{n - 2} β^{n - k - 2} ε_k + αγ \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 3} β^{n - k - 3} ε_k. \quad \forall n \geqslant 3
$$
Next assume that $N$ is a period of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, then\begin{gather*}
x_3 = x_{N + 3} = β^N x_3 + α(1 - γ) \sum_{k = 2}^{N + 1} β^{N - k + 1} ε_k + αγ \sum_{k = 1}^N β^{N - k} ε_k\\
\Longleftrightarrow x_3 = \frac{α}{1 - β^N} \left( (1 - γ) \sum_{k = 2}^{N + 1} β^{N - k + 1} ε_k + γ \sum_{k = 1}^N β^{N - k} ε_k \right),
\end{gather*}
where $ε_{N + 1} = ε_1$. For general $m \geqslant 0$, define $x'_n = x_{n + m}$ and $ε'_n = ε_{n + m}$ for $n \geqslant 1$, analogous derivation shows that$$
x_{m + 3} = x'_3 = \frac{α}{1 - β^N} \left( (1 - γ) \sum_{k = 2}^{N + 1} β^{N - k + 1} ε'_k + γ \sum_{k = 1}^N β^{N - k} ε'_k \right),
$$
i.e.$$
x_n = \frac{α}{1 - β^N} \left( (1 - γ) \sum_{k = 2}^{N + 1} β^{N - k + 1} ε_{n + k - 3} + γ \sum_{k = 1}^N β^{N - k} ε_{n + k - 3} \right), \quad \forall n \geqslant 3 \tag{1}
$$
where $ε_{N + k} = ε_k$ for $k \geqslant 1$.

**Remark:** (1) implies that if $N'$ is a period of $\{ε_n\}$, it is also a period of $\{x_n\}$.

Therefore, on the one hand, sequence $\{x_n\}$ can be completely recovered by $ε_1, \cdots, ε_N$. On the other hand, for arbitrary $N \geqslant 1$ and $ε_1, \cdots, ε_N \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, it suffices to check whether $ε_n = \sgn(x_n)$ holds for $1 \leqslant n \leqslant N$, where $x_1 = x_{N + 1}$, $x_2 = x_{N + 2}$, and $x_n$ ($n \geqslant 3$) is given by (1) .

---

Now consider the case in which $ε_n ≠ 0$ for any $n \geqslant 1$. For $n \geqslant 3$, since $ε_{N + n - 2} = ε_{n - 2}$, then by (1), $ε_n = \sgn(x_n)$ is equivalent to$$
ε_n = \sgn(α) · \sgn\left( ((1 - γ) + β^{N - 1} γ) ε_{n - 2} + ((1 - γ)β + γ) \sum_{k = 2}^N β^{N - k} ε_{n + k - 3} \right). \tag{2}
$$
Note that $(1 - γ) + β^{N - 1} γ > 0$, $(1 - γ)β + γ > 0$, and$$
(1 - γ) + β^{N - 1} γ > ((1 - γ)β + γ) \sum_{k = 2}^N β^{N - k} \Longleftrightarrow γ < \frac{1 - 2β + β^N}{2(1 - β)(1 - β^{N - 1})}.
$$
If $γ < \dfrac{1 - 2β + β^N}{2(1 - β)(1 - β^{N - 1})}$, or in particular $β < \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $γ \leqslant \dfrac{1 - 2β}{2(1 - β)}$, then (2) is equivalent to$$
ε_n = \sgn(α) · ε_{n - 2}. \tag{3}
$$

To simplify the discussion below, define shift operator $s_m$ for $m \geqslant 1$ and reversion operator $r$ as $s_m(x)_n = x_{n + m}$ and $r(x)_n = -x_n$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

**Case 1.1:** $α > 0$. Now (3) becomes $ε_n = ε_{n - 2}$ for all $n \geqslant 3$.

- If $(ε_1, ε_2) = (1, 1)$, then $x_n = \dfrac{α}{1 - β}$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

  If $(ε_1, ε_2) = (1, -1)$, then $x_{2n - 1} = -x_{2n} = \dfrac{α(1 - 2γ)}{1 + β}$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

  If $(ε_1, ε_2) = (-1, 1)$,  then $x_{2n - 1} = -x_{2n} = -\dfrac{α(1 - 2γ)}{1 + β}$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

  If $(ε_1, ε_2) = (-1, -1)$, then $x_n = -\dfrac{α}{1 - β}$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

**Case 1.2:** $α < 0$. Now (3) becomes $ε_n = -ε_{n - 2}$ for all $n \geqslant 3$. Note that all the four possibilities of $(ε_1, ε_2)$ can be generated by the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2) = (1, 1)$ with shift operators and reversion operators. Thus it suffices to consider the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2) = (1, 1)$, then for all $n \geqslant 1$,$$
x_{4n - 3} = -x_{4n - 1} = -\frac{α}{1 + β^2} (1 - β - 2γ),\\
x_{4n - 2} = -x_{4n} = -\frac{α}{1 + β^2} (1 + β - 2βγ).
$$

Analogously, by singling out $ε_{n - 3}$ instead of $ε_{n - 2}$ in (2), it can be proved that if $γ > \dfrac{1 - 2β + 2β^2 - β^N}{2(1 - β)^2}$, or in particular $β < \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $γ \geqslant \dfrac{1 - 2β + 2β^2}{2(1 - β)^2}$, then (2) is equivalent to$$
ε_n = \sgn(α) · ε_{n - 3}. \tag{4}
$$

**Case 2.1:** $α > 0$. Now (4) becomes $ε_n = ε_{n - 3}$ for all $n \geqslant 4$. In the eight possibilities of $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3)$, $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, 1, 1)$ and $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (-1, -1, -1)$ yield a constant sequence by the remark above, and all the rest can be generated by the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, 1, -1)$ with shift operators and reversion operators. Thus it suffices to consider the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, 1, -1)$, then for all $n \geqslant 1$,$$
x_{3n - 2} = \frac{α}{1 - β^3} (1 + β - β^2 - 2(β - β^2)γ),\\
x_{3n - 1} = \frac{α}{1 - β^3} (2(1 - β^2)γ - 1 + β + β^2),\\
x_{3n} = -\frac{α}{1 - β^3} (2(1 - β)γ - 1 + β - β^2).
$$

**Case 2.2:** $α < 0$. Now (4) becomes $ε_n = -ε_{n - 3}$ for all $n \geqslant 4$. In the eight possibilities of $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3)$, $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, -1, 1)$ and $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (-1, 1, -1)$ yield a sequence of period $2$ by the remark above, which is the same as the ones in case 1.1, and all the rest can be generated by the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, 1, 1)$ with shift operators and reversion operators. Thus it suffices to consider the case in which $(ε_1, ε_2, ε_3) = (1, 1, -1)$, then for all $n \geqslant 1$,$$
x_{6n - 5} = -x_{6n - 2} = -\frac{α}{1 + β^3} (1 + β - β^2 - 2βγ),\\
x_{6n - 4} = -x_{6n - 1} = -\frac{α}{1 + β^3} (1 + β + β^2 - 2β^2 γ),\\
x_{6n - 3} = -x_{6n} = -\frac{α}{1 + β^3} (-1 + β + β^2 + 2γ).
$$

It can be verified that the sequences in case 1.1 to case 2.2 indeed satisfy the given recurrence relation.

Comment: I bet my non-existent fortune that the person who upvoted this has felt intimidated and hasn't even bothered to read it. The problem with this argument is that it has a beginning (we *assume* the sequence to have period $N$), but it has no end (from this assumption we draw the conclusion that, if $\alpha < 0$, the sequence has two subsequences (of odd and, respectively, even indices), each one alternating between two values). How does the conclusion contradict the hypotheses, in order for us to conclude that no such $N$ exists? It is not clear.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't know if you're trying to intimidate me or not, but I'm pretty sure that you haven't bothered to read the answer carefully. In fact, the first part is about deriving a necessary condition, i.e. **if** $\{x_n\}$ has a period $N$ then what the terms should be. And the second part solves a special case, i.e. the case in which $γ<\dfrac{1-2β+β^N}{2(1-β)(1-β^{N-1})}$.

Comment: @Saad I have been looking over your answer and I have to say that up to this--> ("For general $m \geqslant 0$, define $x'_n = x_{n + m}$ and $ε'_n = ε_{n + m}$ for $n \geqslant 1$, analogous derivation shows that$$") everything makes sense. I was wondering why can you say that in general?

Comment: @Hidaw Because the new sequence satisfies the same recurrence relation, i.e.$$x'_n=βx'_{n-1}+α(1-γ)x'_{n-2}+αγx'_{n-3}.$$

Comment: @Saad thank you so much. I will keep looking over it and if I have any other questions I hope you don't mind if I connect you again

Comment: @Hidaw Feel free to ask me, but I'm not online for the next five or six hours so the reply might be late.

Comment: @Saad: Your comment doesn't contradict mine: you derive a necessary, but not *sufficient* condition for $x_n$ to be periodic; next, *assuming* that it is periodic, you derive its formula. But the original question remains: is $x_n$ periodic? When? (I.e. can we find *sufficient* conditions for either periodicity, or non-periodicity?) If I read your post correctly, it doesn't answer any of these questions, therefore I too could ironically reply that your post should be a comment rather than an answer. And no, not trying to intimidate anybody here, I'm too old for this game.

Comment: @Saad: Also, note the intelligent remark in **Cesareo**'s answer: *"Due to the structure $x_n = \beta x_{n-1}+\cdots$ there is an exponential component all along $n \to \infty$ which eliminates the periodic behavior possibility."* You, too, obtain a term of $\beta ^{n-3} x_3$ and so do I. This, indeed, is a strong suggestion (even though not a proof) that periodicity is not possible.

Comment: @AlexM. It seems that you have conveniently overlooked all the discussions in the second part, where sufficient conditions, with explicit formulae, are presented.

Answer (score 3):

Calling

$$\delta(u,v)=\alpha(1-\gamma)\mbox{sign}(u)+\alpha\gamma \mbox{sign}(v)
$$

we have

$$
\min_{u,v}\delta(u,v)  \le \alpha(1-\gamma)\mbox{sign}(x_{n-2})+\alpha\gamma \mbox{sign}(x_{n-3})\le \max_{u,v}\delta(u,v)
$$

and the recurrences

$$
x_n^i = \beta x_{n-1}^i+\min_{u,v}\delta(u,v)\\
x_n^s = \beta x_{n-1}^s+\max_{u,v}\delta(u,v)\\
$$

have the solutions

$$
x_n^i = C_0 \beta^{n-1}+\frac{(1-\beta^n)}{\beta-1}\min_{u,v}\delta(u,v)\\
x_n^s = C_0 \beta^{n-1}+\frac{(1-\beta^n)}{\beta-1}\max_{u,v}\delta(u,v)\\
$$

and after a little transient

$$
x_n^i \le x_n\le x_n^s
$$

Attached the plot for $x_n^i, x_n^s$ in red and $x_n$ in blue. Note that the recurrences $x_n^i, x_n^s$ should begin at $x_3$. The values assumed are $\alpha=-3,\beta = 0.25, \gamma = 0.75$ and the initial conditions $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are random values in the range $(-10, 10)$

[image]

NOTE

Due to the structure

$$
x_n = \beta x_{n-1}+\cdots
$$

there is an exponential component all along $n\to\infty$ which eliminates the periodic behavior possibility.

If instead we consider the recurrence

$$
x_n = \alpha(1-\gamma)\mbox{sign}(x_{n-2})+\alpha\gamma \mbox{sign}(x_{n-3})
$$

with $\beta = 0$ then periodic solutions can appear when the initial conditions $x_1, x_2, x_3$ have different signs as for instance $x_1=1,x_2 = -1, x_3 = 0$

[image]

or $x_1=1,x_2 = -1, x_3 = 1$

[image]

To solve

$$
z_n = \beta z_{n-1}+\alpha(1-\gamma)+\alpha\gamma
$$

which is a linear recurrence we use the fact

$$
z_n = z_n^h+z_n^p\\
z_n^h -\beta z_{n-1}^h = 0\\
z_n^p -\beta z_{n-1}^p=\alpha(1-\gamma)+\alpha\gamma
$$

then easily we find $z_n^h = C\beta^{n-1}$. Now considering $z_n^p = C_n\beta^{n-1}$ and substituting into the particular we can find also the recurrence for $C_n$ which is

$$
C_n-C_{n-1} = \alpha\beta^{1-n}
$$

with solution

$$
C_n = \frac{\alpha  \beta  \left(1-\beta ^{-n}\right)}{\beta -1}
$$

and finally

$$
z_n =  C\beta^{n-1}+ \frac{\alpha  \beta  \left(1-\beta ^{-n}\right)}{\beta -1}\beta^{n-1}=C \beta^{n-1}+\frac{\alpha(1-\beta^n)}{\beta-1}
$$

The general solution can be computed with the help of the following MATHEMATICA script

```
x2 = 2; x3 = 3; x1 = 1;
path = {x1, x2, x3};
beta = 0.5; alpha = 10; gamma = 3;
For[i = 1, i <= 30, i++, x4 = beta x3 + alpha (1 - gamma) Sign[x2] + alpha gamma Sign[x1]; 
AppendTo[path, x4]; x1 = x2; x2 = x3; x3 = x4]

ListPlot[path, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: If you do not mind can you please explain how you came to the solutions?

Comment: @Hidaw Please. See attached note.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, I have started looking at your solution again and I am a little confused what the role of the exponents are? Also $z_n^h -\beta z_{n-1}^h = 0$ should it be $z_n^h -\beta z_{n-1}^h = \alpha$ ?

Comment: @Hidaw $z^h$ indicates the homogeneous solution and $z^p$ indicates a particular solution. This is a property of linear recurrences.

Comment: and is it the same thing for $$ x_n^i = \beta x_{n-1}^i-\alpha(1-\gamma)-\alpha\gamma\\ x_n^s = \beta x_{n-1}^s+\alpha(1-\gamma)+\alpha\gamma\\ $$?

Comment: @Hidaw Yes. I used $z$ instead to avoid index notation problems.